# Error saving environment when using rmarkdown

Tags: r, lazy-loading

When I have run `rmarkdown` a couple of times in an R session and try to save the workspace image (e.g., when exiting), I sometimes get the following error:

```
Error in save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version =
version,  :    
  cannot open file '/path/to/my/workspace/rmarkdown_file_cache/docx/diffbind_SS_a24a9612f1c7bc111ac230ebcefdb453.rdb': No such file or directory 
In addition: Warning message: 
In save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version = version,  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

`traceback()` does not show anything informative:

```
2: save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version = version, 
       ascii = ascii, compress = compress, envir = .GlobalEnv, precheck = FALSE)
1: save.image()
```

This behavior is erratic, or at least I could not find a pattern; thus, I can't give you a minimal working example. It happens from time to time. However, it obviously depends on the `cache=TRUE` option to knitr chunks.

Apparently, for some weird reason R needs the rmarkdown lazy load database and somehow. My questions:

- Why? I mean, where in my environment is there a reference to that file? Why does `save.image()` need it?
- Related: what can I do to save my environment?
- How can I better debug what is happening?
- How can I avoid it? (I have to use `cache=TRUE`).

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to reproduce but I recently got a similar error when I wanted to save a dataset, not the whole environment, though.

I assume, you made sure that the directory exists and Rmarkdown tries to save to the right place, and you have enough disk space to save your workspace.

My problem was due to a session crash. I solved it

- copying the `session` (under .rstudio in Linux) to something like `session_orig`
- deleting the session directory
- restarting R

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use rstudio